Redis Pub/Sub migrate to kafka
Currently, I'm have a Redis pub/sub system ,in which i have 2 tomcats.
where one tomcat will be the publisher and both will be the subscribers.
my Use case :-
i have 3 customers. i get data from all customers and it will be added to mysql database.
publisher picks 10 records of each customer and gives to the subscribers and this cycle repeats.
how do i migrate this to kafka? with same 2 tomcat configuration.Please help
i have tried using chatgpt phind but didnot fine any solution
